# java-syntax only runs on first Java buffer

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-java

I'm using neovim v0.4.4, vim-plug, and [uiiaoo/java-syntax.vim](https://github.com/uiiaoo/java-syntax.vim).

For some unknown reason(s), syntax highlighting from java-syntax only works on the 1st java buffer. For example:

```
$ nvim file1.java
:e file2.java
```

```
$ nvim notJava.txt
:vs file1.java
:sp file2.java
```

In both cases, only `file1.java` has syntax highlighting from java-syntax, while `file2` doesn't.

My init.vim

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
syntax on

" In vim-plug
    Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
    Plug 'uiiaoo/java-syntax.vim', {'for': 'java'}

" For coc.nvim
let g:coc_global_extensions = [
    \ 'coc-java',
    \ 'coc-highlight',
]
```

I don't see anything here that would interfere with java-syntax. What might be the cause for only the first Java buffer getting the syntax highlighting?

Comment: If java-syntax is setup correctly, the for clause should be unnecessary. Filetype plugins and syntaxes already only load when needed, so you’re not usually saving anything extra there. I wonder if somehow that’s what’s getting in the way?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I added the `for` just in case. The problem was there before adding `for`.

Comment: Does `:set ft?` tell you `filetype=java` in both `file1.java` and `file2.java`?

Comment: @filbranden The default java syntax highlighting works for all Java files. It's just java-syntax.vim that doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnZhau [This line](https://github.com/uiiaoo/java-syntax.vim/blob/master/syntax/java.vim#L17) in `java-syntax.vim` looks odd: `let b:current_syntax = "java-syntax.vim"`. I believe it should set it to `"java"`, which matches the file type... I haven't had time to check whether this can be what causes the issue you're having, but that's where I would have started...

Comment: In both cases (1st Java buffer & later buffers), `set ft?` returns `filetype=java` & `set current_syntax?` returns the error `E518: Unknown option: current_syntax?` I've also tried disabling `coc-java` to check for conflict but no difference.

Comment: I've found that disabling `sheerun/vim-polyglot` solved the issue. I'll update & answer with furthur details after I've got `polyglot` to work with `java-syntax`.

Comment: Try `echo b:current_syntax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that disabling [`sheerun/vim-polyglot`](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) solved the problem. I'm not sure why exactly polyglot was causing it, but seeing as Java isn't supported by polyglot, I disabled it by putting the following line *before* polyglot is loaded.

```
let g:polyglot_disabled = ['java']
```

For reference, here's my plugin portion (I'm using vim-plug)

```
call plug#begin('$HOME/.config/nvim/plugged')
   " Some other plugins
    let g:polyglot_disabled = ['java']
    Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
call plug#end()
```